# error Installing CNTK for Python 3.9 on anaconda

Tags: anaconda, platform, cntk

I want to install CNTK with anaconda prompt (Python version 3.9.12)

I used following command:

```
pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/GPU/cntk_gpu-2.7.post1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

and got this error:

```
ERROR: cntk_gpu-2.7.post1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

What is the right link that support my platform?

Comment: No One have idea here about this surprise!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are trying to install for Windows OS. What is your OS platform? The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/) says it supports 64-bit Linux or 64-bit Windows

Answer (score 0):

CNTK is no longer actively developed, latest version is 2.7 which works with Python 3.6
That means, Python 3.9 isn't supported.
You can refer to official CNTK page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Setup-Windows-Python?tabs=cntkpy26